# SAS - Transform dataset from wide to tall using arrays

Tags: arrays, sas, transpose

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
OBS     S1   S2   S3
before  10   15   13
after   5    7    8
```

I'm trying to use arrays in SAS to convert it to a table that looks like this:

```
SUBJ    BEFORE    AFTER
1       10        5
2       15        7
3       13        8
```

I'm still new to SAS. I'm thinking that I need to set up a 2x3 array that has the form:

```
10  15  13
5   7   8
```

then loop though and assign the values.

This is what I have so far, but it is only capturing the first row of the original table:

```
DATA tall;
  input obs $ score1-score3;

  array rowscores(3) score1-score3;
  array allscores(2,3) _TEMPORARY_;

  do i=1 to 2;
    do j=1 to 3;
      allscores(i,j) = rowscores(j);
    end;
  end;

  do k=1 to 3;
    subj = k;
    before = allscores(1,k);
    after = allscores(2,k);
    output;
  end;

  keep subj before after;

  DATALINES;
before  10  15  13
after   5   7   8 
;
RUN;
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: SAS only processes one line at a time and arrays are only shortcuts to variables. This solution depends on you knowing the structure of the data, at which point you may as well type out the new dataset. In this case it is significantly more efficient to use a PROC TRANSPOSE rather than an array method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your data step to work you need to move your `INPUT` statement inside of your first DO loop.

To make this transformation this way you need to know a lot about the data  before the data step is compiled.  I think you need to know this information:

```
%let ncols=3 ;
%let nrows=2 ;
%let have_cols = s1-s3 ;
%let want_cols = before after ;
```

So if you did know that information then you could read the whole dataset into a temporary array and then when you get to the end write it back out.

```
data want ;
  set have end=eof;
  array storage (&nrows,&ncols) _temporary_;
  array cols &have_cols ;
  do i=1 to &ncols;
     storage(_n_,i)=cols(i) ;
  end;
  if eof then do;
    do subj=1 to &ncols;
      do j=1 to &nrows;
        array want &want_cols ;
        want(j) = storage(j,subj);
      end;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  keep subj &want_cols ;
run;
```

Probably much easier to just use `PROC TRANSPOSE`.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want ;
   var s1-s3 ;
   id obs ;
run;
```

You could then change the _NAME_ variable into your SUBJ variable or just generate one.

```
data want;
  subj+1;
  set want;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like `PROC TRANSPOSE` is the way to go with this one.